# How can I map array of strings in c# to object properties using automapper

Tags: c#, arrays, string, automapper

```
public class DummyDto
{
    public string Artx_text_value_1;
    public string Artx_text_value_2;
}
```

I have such method which is mapping array od strings to properties to DummyDto.

```
public void MapAddress(DummyDto addreAccClrgInfoSender, string[] addressLines)
{
     for (var i = 0; i < adress.Length; i++)
     {
         var propertyInfo = addreAccClrgInfoSender.GetType().GetProperty($"Artx_text_value_{i+1}");
         propertyInfo?.SetValue(addreAccClrgInfoSender, adress[i]);
     }
}
```

How I can map it using automapper? I wish to have a profile for DummyDto which will dynamically map array of strings to properties. DummyDto can have more Artx_text_value_1

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: Is there a limit to address lines?